Loading configuration parameters from file in a SystemVerilog testbench
I'm trying to write a SystemVerilog testbench, which loads pre-calculated configuration parameters from a file.
My problem is that SystemVerilog seems to be rather strict regarding "constant expressions". If I understand the LRM correctly, typical configuration (such as module parameterization, and range specifications in vector declarations) must be elaboration-time constant. However, things like file accesses happen later, at simulation time.
I'm coming from a VHDL background, where my typical workflow involves loading test configurations (for many thousands of pre-computed test cases) from files. Have I missed a simple trick, or is it not possible to do the same in SystemVerilog?
Assuming it is not possible, how would a SystemVerilog expert do this? The only idea I could think of was to auto-generate SystemVerilog packages containing the configuration data (instead of raw data files). That way, everything would be accessible at elaboration time.
However, that would be quite an ugly hack. And I couldn't think of a neat way to programmatically access thousands of different test cases. (A nice thing about using files was that file names could be constructed programmatically using simple string manipulations).
Minimal example
Here's a minimal example, showing that a parameter read from a file cannot be used in some of the ways I would like.
example.txt (just contains a number, in ASCII):
123

example.sv:
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Module
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
module my_module #(int PARAM);
endmodule

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Testbench
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
module tb;
    
    function automatic int read_file(input string filename);
        const int fid = $fopen(filename, "r");
        var int value;
        $fscanf(fid, "%d", value);
        $fclose(fid);
        return value;
    endfunction
    
    // Load a number from a file.
    const int PARAM = read_file("example.txt");
    
    // ERROR: Ranges must be bound by constant expressions.
    const bit [PARAM-1:0] x = 0;
    
    // ERROR: Parameter expressions must be constant.
    my_module #(PARAM) M();
endmodule


@toolic Yes, these are reusable components that have been used in countless designs, dating back about 20 years.

You would normally pass the parameters from the tool command line. These are specific to each simulator. For example, something like -g tb.PARAM=10.
You'd have a script that reads the configuration file and converts is to the appropriate list of command line args.

I use VUnit, so that fixes the syntax differences between simulators. I can just load all the config files in the VUnit Python script and pass the parameters into my testbench. Great idea!

Although -g option is handy, runtime overriding parameters can prevent many compiler optimizations from happening, slowing down your testbenches.

A const variable is not a compile time constant; it is a write once at run-time initialization. For static variables, that happens once at time 0. For automatic variables, that happens each time you enter the procedural scope where the variable is declared.
Compile time constants are a literal like 1234, or a parameter that can be set with a constant expression of other parameters and literals. Constants are required for values that define things like data type widths.
You can use compiler  `define macros that can be set from a file or the command line. But is the file is automatically generated then best thing to do is generate a SystemVerilog package with these parameter defined.

My experience of auto-generated source code is that it tends to be a recipe for multiple different kinds of disaster (not to mention it means facing the wrath of frustrated colleagues who can't find the mysterious missing packages). Similar problems can apply to macros, if taken too far (since they're also text manipulation of source code, and difficult to debug). I also need to maintain portability between HDL languages, so it's difficult to justify duplicating the data like this. In my specific case, I think -g (with a performance hit) is the lesser evil.
